# views use the same css class for both sidebar and article, blocks me from resizing main content

Tags: views, theming

I have a front page view of articles that are displayed as trimmed as well as a sidebar block. This is all fine I have my layout all good. The issue is, if I click on an article to go to it's full page view then the article retains the css class from the front-page so I am stuck with a 70% full page article.

The main issue is that both my articles and latest articles (sidebar) use the same class name "content". I tried to edit templates in order to override this but to no avail. All blocks use the "content" class which makes it uneditable!

*edit* in fact every block I have uses the class="content"!

Any help would be appreciated!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can either define different classes for the teaser and fullpage views of your content type using templates, edit the views template or define your css using the class .front or .node-type-article ?

For 1) create a node--content-type-name.tpl.php file and use the `if (!$page) { // teaser view` switch to output a different class or template.

For 2) create a views-view-unformatted--view-name.tpl.php file and wrap it in a different class

For 3) use the built in drupal classes that are outputted into your themes body tag in your themes html.tpl.php file with `<?php print $classes; ?>`. Edit your css to specify your style usinf `.front .article {} .not-front .article {}` etc ..

Or edit your block.tpl.php file and remove the class .content

Comment: ok I tried to change in block.tpl to 
<pre><code><?php if (!$is_front): ?>
  <div class="content-front"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php print $content ?>
  </div>
<?php else: ?>
  <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php print $content ?>
  </div>
<?php endif?></code></pre>
If I look at the unformatted-trending-topics file this is where it outputs the class: <pre><code><div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>></code></pre> what should I put?

Comment: sorry formatting the code in here doesn't work

Comment: the issue is that a wrapper doesn't work on this particular tpl because it's already rows. `<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>`

Comment: what about the template for the content type, rather than using the !$is_front on the block template or editing the views template? I usually set up 2 different templates for the teaser and the full page views. This is hard to go on from the info you've given. Do you have a link?

Comment: and in the view temnplate you could wrap <div class="myviewclass">  <?php 
    foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
   print $row;
    }
  ?>

Comment: I tried and nothing works :( here is a link: http://groovymotion.com/blog you can see that the main content and sidebar have the same information but it's just a test case...and if you click on any link they all take the 70% width defined by "content"

Comment: are you flushing your cache / rescanning template files in views?

Comment: yes for both front page and sidebar but for block.tpl where can I get it rescanned? or it's just when I flush the cache?

Comment: Yes, just by flushing the template cache. Do you have a custom block theme? In your block.tpl.php named correctly? block--block--[block-id].tpl.php

Comment: the only thing in there that has an id is `<div id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>`

Comment: ok I managed to force front-page articles and sidebar to have their own content class and articles work perfectly in their full page view. only thing left is the sidebar seems to not float properly

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the culprit! It's the pager that for some reason decides to take 100% of width, so it forces the sidebar to break apart! :)